# Grouping elements based on an identifier in regular expression

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a long string that looks like:

```
s = 'label("id1","A") label("id1","B") label("id2", "C") label("id2","A") label("id2","D") label("id3","A")'
```

I would like to use regular expressions to creates lists of labels based on the id.

To be more clear, from the string `s` in the example I would like to end up with a list of results that looks like:

```
[("id1", ["A","B"]),
 ("id2", ["C","A","D"]),
 ("id3", ["A"])]
```

Using regular expressions I managed to fetch the ids and the elements:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'label\((\S*),(\S*)\)')
results = re.findall(regex,s)
```

With this code, `results` looks like:

```
[('"id1"', '"A"'),
 ('"id1"', '"B"'),
 ('"id2"', '"A"'),
 ('"id2"', '"D"'),
 ('"id3"', '"A"')]
```

Is there an easy way to obtain the data already grouped correctly from the regular expression?

Comment: In the desired results I have grouped the elements in a list (eg. ["A","B"], but even a tuple or a set will be fine!

Comment: id's are always sorted?

Comment: ideally, but I would not rely on that..

Comment: Note that your regex leaves a bunch of (I assume unnecessary) quotes behind, and your code does not capture the id2:"C" pair because there is a rogue space in one spot in the data.  See my answer for a fix for these problems.

Comment: Hi Brionius, actually I need the quotes. And the space I assume is a typo, but not essentially a problem in my case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the `findall()` results and collect them in a [`collections.defaultdict` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Do adjust your regular expressions to not include the quotes, and add some whitespace tolerance, though:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

regex = re.compile(r'label\("([^"]*)",\s*"([^"]*)"\)')
results = defaultdict(list)

for id_, tag in regex.findall(s):
    results[id_].append(tag)

print results.items()
```

You can replace `list` with `set` and `append()` with `add()` if all you want is unique values.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> import re
>>> s = 'label("id1","A") label("id1","B") label("id2", "C") label("id2","A") label("id2","D") label("id3","A")'
>>> regex = re.compile(r'label\("([^"]*)",\s*"([^"]*)"\)')
>>> results = defaultdict(list)
>>> for id_, tag in regex.findall(s):
...     results[id_].append(tag)
... 
>>> results.items()
[('id2', ['C', 'A', 'D']), ('id3', ['A']), ('id1', ['A', 'B'])]
```

You can sort this result too, if so desired.

Answer (score 0):

Is postprocessing the result you get acceptable?

If so,

```
import re
# edited your regex to get rid of the extra quotes, and to allow for the possible space that occurs in label("id2", "C")
regex = re.compile(r'label\(\"(\S*)\",\ ?\"(\S*)\"\)')
results = re.findall(regex,s)
resultDict = {}
for id, val in results:
    if id in resultDict:
        resultDict[id].append(val)
    else:
        resultDict[id] = [val]

# if you really want a list of tuples rather than a dictionary:
resultList = resultDict.items()
```